# Google Maps API stuck on loading producing errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, ssl

I have plenty of maps in my website and only recently since I added a SSL certificate to my website the site has started to produce errors and the map has stopped loading full stop.

One of the maps on the website works perfectly which makes me believe that this is nothing to do with the API and in fact it is something to do with the code.

```
function gd_initialize_ac() {
      // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search
      // to geographical location types.
                        autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
                            /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('detail_page_map_canvas_fromAddress')),
                            {types: ['geocode']});
                        // When the user selects an address from the dropdown,
                        // populate the address fields in the form.
                        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
                            gd_fillInAddress_ac();
                        });
                    }

                    function gd_fillInAddress_ac() {
                        //submit the form
                        jQuery('#directions').trigger('click');
                    }
```

This is the error that is being produced in the inspect on Google Chrome.

[image: This is the error that is being produced in the inspect on Google Chrome.]

And then this is the code that is linked to the error that is being produced. Please bare in mind that there is a https on this site now, I don't know if this has relevance but..

What I've attempted so far:

- Renaming all the http:// to https:// (no hope)
- Adding &libaries at the end of the api within the javascript API. (I saw this on another answer)

Here is where it is getting the Google Maps API Key from.

```
function rgmk_find_add_key( $url, $original_url, $_context ) {
$key = get_option( 'rgmk_google_map_api_key' );

// If no key added no point in checking
if ( ! $key ) {
    return $url;
}

if ( strstr( $url, "maps.google.com/maps/api/js" ) !== false || strstr( $url, "maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js" ) !== false ) {// it's a Google maps url

    if ( strstr( $url, "key=" ) === false ) {// it needs a key
        $url = add_query_arg( 'key',$key,$url);
        $url = str_replace( "&#038;", "&amp;", $url ); // or $url = $original_url
    }

}

return $url;  }
```

Comment: Could you please post the `script` tag which loads Google API. I suspect you're not loading `Autocomplete` lib

Comment: It is done via a Wordpress plugin, would you like me to post the plugin's script tag and all of the insides?

Comment: View the source of the webpage, find the script. Then, post it here. You could also post the plugin php source.

Comment: Just added it onto the question

Comment: Any idea on how to do this? I have since tried to add a direct script within the footer at the bottom of the page but still no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was something to do with the jQuery being out of date.

If anyone else has this issue try to update jQuery and it should work perfectly fine!